# Search Launchpad for PPAs matching software or package name?

Tags: ppa, launchpad, search, package-management

Is there a way to search though LaunchPad's PPAs for a certain package name? For instance if I was looking for PPAs with Firefox packages I could search for "firefox" and retrieve a list of all the PPAs which contain a firefox package.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can search for PPAs matching software or package in the following link

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+ppas

[image]

Comment: It even highlights the exact package names when you go through the results.

Comment: @Stefano It does? I wasn't able to confirm that

Answer (score 7):

[Y PPA Manager](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/01/y-ppa-manager-004-released-with-new.html) is a standalone programme that can be used to search PPAs for a certain package. Once some PPAs are found, you can easily list the packages and see what other packages (and their versions) that PPA provides. It also allows for much more precise ("deep") searches than the Launchpad web interface.

You can install the package from the [ppa:webupd8team/y-ppa-manager](https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/y-ppa-manager) PPA.

Answer (score 3):

[ppasearch](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them/7639#7639) looks handy for command line environments.

Comment: Appears to be a ruby script which scrapes the https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+ppa However, it's nice that it provides further drilldown

Comment: I find it disappointing that Ruby developers often make programs that would be much better suited as simply shell scripts.

Answer (score 1):

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+ppas?name_filter=gjots2 will show you PPA that ship the gjots2 package, for example.  No need to install any additional tools.