# Is there an alternative for 'ppasearch' in newer versions of Ubuntu?

Tags: command-line, software-recommendation, ppa

Is there an alternative for [ppasearch](https://launchpad.net/~wrinkliez/+archive/ppasearch) (command-line app) in newer versions of Ubuntu?

ppasearch is only avaiable for 10.10, 10.04 and 9.10.

> [image]

Comment: What did `ppasearch` originally do?

Comment: @kiri same thing as `apt search` but for ppa's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

very easy python script derived from [this gist](https://gist.github.com/marcoceppi/731184/43c8482b60baa09b9822e51d4309a3c965952b31) :

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys, json

cachedir = "/tmp/ppasearch"

from launchpadlib.launchpad import Launchpad
launchpad = Launchpad.login_anonymously('mc-ppa-test', 'production', cachedir)

potential = launchpad.projects.search(text=sys.argv[1])
for p in potential:
    print(p.display_name + "\t" + (p.description or "")[:60] + "\t" + p.web_link)
```

as alternative, i am trying to query the [official web API](https://launchpad.net/+apidoc/1.0.html) directly with curl but i am not sure how to fetch the results:

```
$ curl "https://api.launchpad.net/1.0/projects/+search?field.text=$PACKAGE_NAME"
Object: <lp.registry.model.product.ProductSet object at 0x7f1d80be5df0>, name: '+search'
```

Answer (score 5):

If you're looking to search for a PPA which contains a certain package, you can use the PPA search feature in [Y PPA Manager](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/10/y-ppa-manager-0991-released-with-ubuntu.html) (by [WebUp8](http://www.webupd8.org/)).

1. Install it with these commands:

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/y-ppa-manager
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install y-ppa-manager
   ```
2. Run it by searching for *Y PPA Manager* in the Dash.
3. Click on the "Search in all Launchpad PPAs" button.

   [image]
4. Enter your admin password if prompted.
5. Enter the package name you want to search for.
   Enable the "Basis search" if you want it to go faster, but with less info

   [image]
6. Click "OK". A notification will appear informing you that the search has started,
   wait for a new window with PPAs to appear.
7. You can then choose to add a PPA and other actions.

   [image]

---

As a side note, Y PPA Manager also includes a handy utility called `update-ppa`. It's like `apt-get update`, but only for one PPA.

Usage:

```
sudo -H update-ppa ppa:webupd8team/y-ppa-manager
```

(replace `ppa:webupd8team/y-ppa-manager` with the PPA, with a similar format)

Comment: As far as you know, ppasearch is a command-line util. I have headless Ubuntu server without any GUI.