# Does Calligra have a ppa for ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, calligra

In ubuntu 12.04 Calligra is 2.4.
Now the newest is 2.6.
Does Calligra have a ppa for ubuntu 12.04?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are Calligra version 2.6 backports available on Launchpad [here](https://launchpad.net/~kubuntu-ppa/+archive/backports).

You can add them to your repository through Synaptic using the following line(with instructions provided in the link below):

`deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/kubuntu-ppa/backports/ubuntu YOUR_UBUNTU_VERSION_HERE main`

Or, from a terminal(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>), run the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kubuntu-ppa/backports
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install calligra
```

- [What are PPAs and how do I use them?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them/40351#40351)
- [Are PPA's safe to add to my system and what are some "red flags" to watch out for?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35629/are-ppas-safe-to-add-to-my-system-and-what-are-some-red-flags-to-watch-out)

Comment: [Search Launchpad for PPAs matching software or package name?](http://askubuntu.com/q/16393/28369) Added as a comment, because the OP might wanted to know which PPA is the right one.