# How to find out appropriate ppa repository of a command?

Tags: command-line, repository, add-apt-repository

I want to add commands 'apt-fast' and 'apt-spy' (apt-spy2) into Ubuntu 15.04 - these commands are contained in Debian. How do I find out the suiting ppa repository where they are located at ? With google I had no success. 'apt-fast' is solved then (after type-error) - but 'apt-spy' is still to be solved, after 'apt-spy2' did not help too.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Search Launchpad for PPAs matching software or package name?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/16393/search-launchpad-for-ppas-matching-software-or-package-name)

Comment: @muru - hello I meant this here for certain commands not for packages in general. How can I find out, if a command is contained in a package like package 'bash' ?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install `apt-fast` this way

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:saiarcot895/myppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install apt-fast
```

I see that you tried it and it did not work. But I tested and it works.

You need to be connected to internet to add the repository and also setup proxy if you use one.

Comment: apparently there was an empty-space character too much at first attempt - second attempt here was then successful too ...