# How to find appropriate PPA for installing specific package to solve Unable to locate package?

Tags: apt, package-management, ppa

I wanted to install `OpenJDK-8` on `Ubuntu 14.04`. So as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/378565/485213) I tried to find the correct name of package (which is `openjdk-8-jdk`) and run these commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk
```

But I got:

```
E: Unable to locate package openjdk-8-jdk
```

So I went to [Ubuntu Packages Search](http://packages.ubuntu.com/) and [Ubuntu Updates](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/) and searched for package. But I could not find any thing about `trusty (14.04LTS)` or `trusty-updates`. So I was sure there is no install able package to be installed on `Ubuntu 14.04`.

Of course after sometimes I suddenly found that package belongs to `openjdk-r/ppa` repository and added that:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:openjdk-r/ppa
```

But I want to know how I can find appropriate repository (in above example the `openjdk-r/ppa`) before consuming times and waiting for chance?

Comment: Anyone can make a ppa and name it like anything. In general, google is the best option.

Comment: search for `openjdk ppa` in google. first result is the ppa on launchpad. For other things, search google for `packagename ppa` and you'll found it most of the time.

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/q/16393/15003.

Comment: @edwinksl,  I was looking for that link too, but I always forget the way to that page (for searching in PPA's)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually, I do as Jacob Vlijm said through a search engine DuckDuckGo/Google. Most of the time, they bring well results with users feedback from the web.

But not everything, in some cases I back to launchpad site itself which shows me always the final results:

1. Goto the main page https://launchpad.net/
2. Search with more keywords to minimize noise (other releases, arch's, ..)

   Example: [`ppa openjdk-8-jdk amd64 trusty`](https://launchpad.net/+search?field.text=ppa%20openjdk-8-jdk%20amd64%20trusty&field.actions.search=Search)

   Skip the top part (projects). The first one looks like what I want

   > [amd64 build of openjdk-8 8u91-b14-0ubuntu4~14.04 : OpenJDK ...](https://launchpad.net/~openjdk-r/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/+build/9611145)
   >  
   >   Apr 22, 2016 ... “PPA for OpenJDK uploads (restricted)” team ... OpenJDK builds (all archs); 
   >   amd64 build of openjdk-8 8u91-b14-0ub... created ... Series: Trusty.

   However, the link took me to a buildlog, on top-right area you can see *Build details* → → *Archive* → *[OpenJDK builds (all archs)](https://launchpad.net/~openjdk-r/+archive/ubuntu/ppa)* which is the PPA link.
3. Check if the PPA still has that build for trusty, by setting the filter:

   *Overview of published packages* → *Published in*: `trusty` then press *Filter*